# Netbeans errors "The attribute target is not defined in the component outputStylesheet"

Tags: jsf, netbeans, facelets

I have entered the following code:

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css" target="body" />
```

The problem is that it is giving me an error on target="body" saying:

```
The attribute target is not defined in the component outputStylesheet
```

In the html part if the html I have the following:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">
```

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: I believe that you don't need to specify the attribute target.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look in the [tag documentation of `<h:outputStylesheet>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/outputStylesheet.html). It indeed doesn't list `target` attribute. Perhaps you're confusing with the one from [`<h:outputScript>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/outputScript.html).

The `<h:outputStylesheet>` is by default **always** relocated to HTML `<head>`, for the very simple reason because it's illegal to have a `<style>` or `<link>` element inside the HTML `<body>`. The `<h:outputScript>` however is by default located at exactly the same location as where it's been declared. The `<script>` element as generated by it may be placed anywhere in the HTML `<head>` or `<body>`. You can let JSF auto-relocate this by setting the `target` attribute to `head` (will then appear in `<head>`) or `body` (will then appear in end of `<body>`).

Just remove it. If `target="body"` would theoretically have worked, it would only end up in illegal HTML output anyway.

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css" />
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, a resource library name of "css" is semantically wrong. Put it in the resource name.

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="css/style.css" />
```

#### See also:

- [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used)

Comment: The way the OP uses the command is also used in Oracle's JEE7 Tutorial in the jsf/reservation example. So did they have it wrong as well?

Comment: Yes, it is incorrect in the JavaEE tutorial: `<h:outputStylesheet name="css/stylesheet.css" target="head"/>`. Here: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-facelets009.htm

Comment: Also, the JavaEE tutorial examples contain this line as well... (reservation example)

Comment: @AVC: it's currently already fixed. They don't use `library="css"` anymore.